# Angular 2 Service call from a generic function

Tags: angular, angular2-services, subscribe, angular2-http

I have a function which I use to decide which service has to be called and I have a template for functions to call using the service that is returned from that function. This function makes a call to http.get/http.post etc which return an Observable and do a map on the data being returned. 
As you can see below I do a subscribe here to a generic function template inside a service based on the service name. The issue is , with the service not being called directly but through a function creates an issue in subscribe() where the data is marked due to being implicitly of type 'any'. Is there a way to do type casting inside subscribe? 
Like

```
subscribe(
 data:string => {

})
```

Else I am forced to do switch on the appname to directly call the service injected in the constructor. Even here I am injecting through the constructor but I can reduce the code lines this way.

My code --

```
export class MyComponent {

private service:any;
private appName:string;

constructor(private _service1:Service1,
route:ActivatedRoute){
this.appName = this.route.snapshot.params['app'];
this.service = this.getService(appName);
}

getService(serviceName: string): any {
            var service: {};
            switch (serviceName) {
                case "Service1":
                    service = this._service1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return service;
        }
runJob(){
   this.service.runJob()
   .subscribe(
       data => {
     // My code here. This gives error as data is mentioned as implicitly of type 'any'
       },
      err => {
   // My actions. Same issue here too
  })

}

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can type the passed data like this:

```
myService.getSomething().subscribe((data: DataType) => {
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: True, but a better solution would be to adjust `runJob` so that it returns an `Observable<T>` where `T` is not `any`.